# Setting Variables in IF statements in SQL Server 2014

Tags: variables, if-statement, sql-server-2014

> Msg 134, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>   The variable name '@AsOfDate' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

I am getting this error when running a set of IF statements. Ideally I would simply need to toggle my bit to 1 for the quarter I'm interested in and then execute my code. The `IF` statements would set the dates I need.

I have tried this with `IF` and `ELSE IF`, but neither seems to make a difference. Any suggestions on how I can do this would be greatly appreciated.  Sadly I can't simply have it pick the quarter I'm in (or the one previous) as these reports may be requested at any time.

```
-------------------------
--   Choose Quarter    --
-------------------------
DECLARE @Q1     BIT = 0
DECLARE @Q2     BIT = 0
DECLARE @Q3     BIT = 0
DECLARE @Q4     BIT = 0
DECLARE @Annual BIT = 0
-------------------------
--Q1 
IF @Q1 = '1'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AsOfDate datetime = '2016-03-31'; 
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2016-01-01'
END

--Q2
IF @Q2 = '1'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AsOfDate datetime = '2016-06-30'; 
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2016-04-01'
END

--Q3
IF @Q3 = '1'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AsOfDate datetime = '2016-09-30'; 
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2016-07-01'
END

--Q4
IF @Q4 = '1'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AsOfDate datetime = '2016-12-31'; 
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2016-10-01'
END

-- ANNUAL
IF @Annual = '1'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AsOfDate datetime = '2016-12-31'; 
    DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2016-01-01'
END

-- Check to ensure a time period is set
IF (@Q1 = 0 AND @Q2 = 0 AND @Q3 = 0 AND @Q4 = 0 AND @ANNUAL = 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'NO TIME SET'
END
-- Run Code with dates
ELSE 
BEGIN
```

EDIT:

Disregard... actually reading my error and code clearly points to my declares being an issue not the setting of the variable... Solution is to declare the variables outside of my IF statements and SET them in the statement.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find the solution to your issue. You should post your solution as an answer instead of editing your question so that other people will be able to see it.

Comment: Please post an answer, do not update your question's code to be correct. That's just confusing.

Comment: Agreed, I'm going to re-edit my question to show the original error code.  Not sure why I didn't think to simply post an answer, I guess because it happened RIGHT as I posed the question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was declaring in each IF statement instead of declaring prior to all the IF statements.  Below is the updated version of the code.

```
DECLARE @ASOfDate   DATETIME
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME
-------------------------
--   Choose Quarter    --
-------------------------
DECLARE @Q1     BIT = 0
DECLARE @Q2     BIT = 0
DECLARE @Q3     BIT = 0
DECLARE @Q4     BIT = 0
DECLARE @Anual  BIT = 0
-------------------------
--Q1 
    IF @Q1 = '1'
        BEGIN
            SET @AsOfDate = '2016-03-31' ; SET @StartDate = '2016-01-01'
        END
--Q2
    IF @Q2 = '1'
        BEGIN
            SET @AsOfDate = '2016-06-30' ; SET @StartDate = '2016-04-01'
        END
--Q3
    IF @Q3 = '1'
        BEGIN
            SET @AsOfDate = '2016-09-30' ; SET @StartDate = '2016-07-01'
        END
--Q4
    IF @Q4 = '1'
        BEGIN
            SET @AsOfDate = '2016-12-31' ; SET @StartDate = '2016-10-01'
        END
--ANUAL
    IF @Anual = '1'
        BEGIN
            SET @AsOfDate = '2016-12-31' ; SET @StartDate = '2016-01-01'
        END
-- Check to ensure a time period is set
IF (@Q1 = 0 AND @Q2 = 0 AND @Q3 = 0 AND @Q4 = 0 AND @ANUAL = 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'NO TIME SET'
    END
-- Run Code with dates
ELSE 
BEGIN
Start of Actual Program using dates shown
END
```